# In iOS, how can I load modal window with the data received from some NSURLConnection?

Tags: ios

In my iPad application, I want to load a modal window with some data.
But those data can be retrieved from a web service call. So, I have created another class and in that class's connectionDidFinishLoading I can have the response data. As the web service call is asynchronous, I have to wait for the data to load the modal window. Can anyone help me with some example code? Should I think in different way?

Thank you all for the prompt reply.
My problem was solved using the NSNotificationCenter. This tutorial was helpful http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WB-QCv_4ANU&feature=plcp

Comment: Is the async connection already working?

Comment: Yes. I can have the data after the modal window is loaded.

Comment: So you should do as rakesh says and not open the window until the connectionFinished method is called.

Answer (score 0):

Either you can load modal window from connectionDidFinishLoading  method. Or you can use delegates to pass data from connectionDidFinishLoading  metod to the window that you are going to present. Refer [this](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/objective-c/the-basics-of-protocols-and-delegates.html) tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

You start the connection this way:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:<#your url string#>];
NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
myData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
con = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

And you need to implement `NSURLConnectionDelegate` delegate.

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
 //append data to your NSMutableData object
 [myData appendData: data];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
  didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{    
    //handle the error
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    //here you can use your NSMutableData object, fill your window with the data etc.
    <#your code#>
}
```

This is just an example. You can read more about it in [NSURLConnectionDelegate Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSURLConnectionDelegate).